# Connecting to ProxySQL via socket - "No such file or directory"

Tags: proxysql

I am trying to connect to ProxySQL from PHP with mysqlnd using the local socket, but I get

> "No such file or directory"

, as the socket would not exist. The same code can connect to the mysql socket with no problem.

Basically I am reproducing what was described at:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/09/19/proxysql-improves-mysql-ssl-connections/

```
<?php
$i = 10000;
$user = 'percona';
$pass = 'percona';
while($i>=0) {
 $mysqli = mysqli_init();

 // ProxySQL
 $link = mysqli_real_connect($mysqli, "localhost",      $user, $pass, "", 6033, "/tmp/proxysql.sock")
 or die(mysqli_connect_error());
 $info = mysqli_get_host_info($mysqli);
 $i--;
 mysqli_close($mysqli);
 unset($mysqli);
}
?>
```

This throws:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

The socket file (/tmp/proxysql.sock) is in fact there:

```
$ ls -all /tmp
total 12
drwxrwxrwt. 11 root     root      4096 Oct  7 17:33 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 28 root     root      4096 Sep 20 17:42 ..
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root     root         6 Aug  8 02:40 .font-unix
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root     root         6 Aug  8 02:40 .ICE-unix
srwxrwxrwx   1 proxysql proxysql     0 Oct  7 17:11 proxysql.sock
```

I can use the mysql client to connect through it:

```
$ mysql -u myuser -p --socket /tmp/proxysql.sock --prompt='ProxySQLClient> '
```

If in the above PHP code I replace the socket file with the MySQL socket, then that works. It is only the proxysql.sock which doesn't work with mysqlnd.

I am using:
mysqlnd version **mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407**
ProxySQL version **2.0.6**

Any idea why the proxysql.sock is not accepted by mysqlnd?

UPDATE: Following @EternalHour's suggestion below, I have also tried moving the proxysql.sock file out of /tmp, but unfortunately that didn't make a difference. I am still receiving the same error.

EDIT (2019-10-08): It turns out this issue has nothing to do with PHP, as netcat throws the same problem too, whether the socket files in in /tmp or in /var/sockets/:

```
$ nc -U /tmp/proxysql.sock
Ncat: No such file or directory.
```

Out of the 3 nodes of the ProxySQL cluster running on the same OS, same kernel version, 1 has this issue, the other 2 allows connection to the socket file in /tmp/proxsql.sock, although over there too, sometimes restarting ProxySQL results in the socket file being created as private (eg not available to other applications)

Comment: Take a look here, https://serverfault.com/questions/614781/php-script-cant-access-tmp-folder. I believe the issue comes from file being in `/tmp` dir. You can try that recommendation or move the .sock file to a different location.

Comment: Thanks @EternalHour, I have already tried that earlier, unfortunately there was no change. But to be sure I have tried again and unfortunately no change, the issue is still the same.

Comment: After moving from proxysql 1.x to 2.x I had to point all of my apps to `/var/lib/proxysql/proxysql.sock`.. I realise you say that the socket is in /tmp but figured I'd mention anyway in case it steers you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didn't really help. I can see the .sock file in /tmp/proxysql.sock, in fact I can relocate it to somewhere else, the problem is that as soon as I point PHP's mysqlnd to it, it says "No such file or directory", while if I point it to the mysql.sock file of MySQL, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Many MySQL Clients have a special handling of  the word`localhost`. `localhost` doesn't mean "use the resolver to resolve `localhost` and connect via TCP" but "use unix domain socket on the default path" to use TCP use `127.0.0.1` instead. If proxySQL also provides a unix domain socket provide that path.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't answer it. The "/tmp/proxysql.sock" is already the path to the socket file of ProxySql. I already use 'localhost' with the intention to trigger the use of the socket. The problem is that mysqlnd says "No such file or directory". The proxysql socket file is there and it is operational when used from the mysql CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry everyone, the issue was embarrassingly simple - it was simply my fault.

When I was changing the socket file's location in ProxySQL Admin I was using the following

update global_variables set variable_value='0.0.0.0:6033;/tmp/proxysql.sock ' where variable_name='mysql-interfaces';
SAVE MYSQL VARIABLES TO DISK;

Yes, that is a space at the end of "/tmp/proxysql.sock ".
When I was changing it to different locations, I only rewrote the first half of that (the folder), never the filename, so I just keep copying the space and hence always got file or directory not found...

Problem solved!

Sorry about it